# How to remove last comma in tags list?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a little snippet for displaying tags separated with commas in WordPress:

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>, ";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Now, how can I remove last comma? Or maybe there is a better way than my above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags();
$tag_count = 1;

$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>" . ( $tag_count < count( $tags ) ? ", " : "");
    $tag_count++;
}
$html .= '</div>';

echo $html;
?>
```

You will just need to setup a count and display the comma if the total number of tags is less than the current count. Once the count equals the total number of tags it will display nothing instead of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to count again and again in the loop.

```
<?php

$tags = get_tags();
$arr_len = count($tags); // Performance matter

$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ($tags as $index => $tag) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>" . ( ($index == $arr_len - 1) ? '' : ', ');
}
$html .= '</div>';

echo $html;
?>
```